# Javascript: How to grab fragment from URL and write it into some PHP?

Tags: javascript, query-string, window.location

On the client side, I want to grab the complete URL from the window location, and write it into a simple PHP function, so I can echo the #fragments back to the user in the HTML.

my URL is structured like this:

```
http://example.com/filename.html#var1=FOO&var2=BAR
```

notice no `?`. The query string delimiter in use must be `#`, if that impacts your proposed solution.

I want to take that complete url exactly as it appears in window location write it into this simple PHP function::

```
<?php
parse_str (parse_url ("$_want_to_write_the_full_URL_here", PHP_URL_FRAGMENT ), $args);
    echo $args['var1'], ' ', $args['var2'];
?>
```

I know I can get get window location like this example:

```
<script>alert(window.location);</script>
```

But how to get it into the PHP, using javascript on the client side?

thank in advance to all you wizards!

Answer (score 2):

Since server side PHP runs before any client side JavaScript runs, the only way to get the data back to PHP is to make a new HTTP request.

There are several ways to do this including:

- The [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) object
- Dynamically generating a script element (as per [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP))
- Dynamically generating an iframe/img/etc
- Assigning a new URI to [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) so the browser leaves the current page
- Dynamically generating a form and calling its `submit()` method

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, good answer. I suspected server side PHP code runs first, so you can't get client side data in there. If I remove PHP from the equation, can you point me in the right direction for a javascript-only solution that will write URL fragments into the HTML when a requirement is that the query string delimiter is `#` instead of `?` ?? I've been trying to solve this for days now. Thanks in advance.